# Proper way to use jquery-confirm

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Im calling a javascript function that contains a jquery-confirm function from button click but cant get it right. It shows the error "JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object". Can someone pls help me out here.

embedding jquery :

```
   <head runat="server"> 
    <title>User Authentication</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.confirm.js"></script>  
</head>
```

javascript code :
`function Confirm()
        {
                $(function(){
                    $.confirm({
                    text: "yes or no",
                    title: "yes or no",
                    confirm: function() {
                        alert('yes');
                    },
                    cancel: function() {
                        alert('no');
                    },
                    confirmButton: "Yes",
                    cancelButton: "No",
                    post: true,
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                    cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"
                });
                });
        }`
code behind :  `btnLogin.OnClientClick = "javascript:return Confirm();";`

Comment: You need to include the <script> tag for JQuery plugin JS file under <head>

Comment: @Thangadurai ahm.. is what i did wrong? or something missing?

Comment: Make sure you have referred JQuery plugin correctly in your code. <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with the path :( but i manually clicked its URL using the GUI of visual studio :( im getting frustrated at this. i added <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> but now it says Object doesn't support property or method 'confirm' :( is their another way for this?

Comment: Refer [here](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) for examples

Answer (score 0):

By writing

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
```

you only add the "plugin-script". Nevertheless you need to add the jQuery base. So add the following line before adding the plugin script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```